# Tips on thinking of a good game mechanic?

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, rpg

I am trying to make a turned based rpg and I really want to know how can i make original game mechanics like Undertale with it's sparing system.I am not really that creative to think of a good game mechanic,I just need tips on how to improve my creativity for game dev because it is really hard for me to think of something original.
Thanks!

Comment: Hey welcome to GameDev, see [help] for on-topic questions, we don't answer questions on what to get started designing. You might want to check out books like The Art of Game Design or Level Up! Game Design that teach a lot of fundamentals of how to build your skills as a designer and how to think up new ideas.

Comment: Undertale's fighting system is a typical genre mish-mash. It combines the classical JRPG turn-based fighting mechanics with the dodging from bullet hell shoot-em-ups. Many interesting game mechanics can result from importing elements from a completely different game genre.

Comment: I am afraid that the question "how to improve my creativity for game dev" is far too broad and subjective for this website. There are countless techniques to come up with ideas and a technique which works for one person doesn't necessarily work for someone else.

Comment: I wrote an answer with guidance, but this question was closed (I think correctly) before I could post it. [It's here for posterity](https://gist.github.com/anko/8784e05263fa33a0c1188881849e1ff8), in case someone finds it helpful or wants to copy it for a more on-topic question.

Comment: @Philipp I am trying to combine undertale with Apotheon idk if its a good idea or not but i will try it.Thanks for the answer tho!

Comment: @Anko Thanks man you wrote all this for?!! thanks!I want to make my game like undertale but I want to add apotheon on it like instead of the heart i will be that guy from apotheon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You copy other ideas. Then by copying and mixing different other ideas, you'll find that they don't work very well together unless you make some adjustments . You do the adjustments (possibly by copying yet another idea from somewhere else) and then you have a new mechanic. At that point you might find that it still doesn't work well, in which case you need to start over.

Do not limit yourself to copying from computer games. You can also copy from board games, movies, reality, etc.